# How to restore Gmail password if I still have an access to this account by redirection

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, gmail, account-recovery

I added another Gmail account to my primary Gmail account years ago through the `Accounts and Imports` option. I can get and send emails to/from this account, but I cannot log in into this account independently, as I have forgotten the password.

I have no access to my then recovery email. I haven't associated this account with any phone number, I did not have a mobile phone then. My secret question was my best friend name and this is a very tricky name to write in English. I have tried many combinations to no avail.

I know that I behaved silly in many ways. However, this is a very important account, much information is associated with it. How can I restore the password for this account? How can I explain to Google that I still have access to it, so it IS mine?

Alternatively, **is there a way to restore this password from Google settings on my local computer? Probably Google is cashing it locally somewhere.**

Comment: You would need to contact Google and provide whatever information they require to regain access to the account.  You might want to in the future verify your recovery options are valid.

Comment: Tried. Provided the last password I remember, the last recovery email I remember - still they refuse to restore.

Comment: Then you are out of luck.  Only Google can get you access to the account in question

Comment: If Gmail stores encrypted passwords locally, I probably have some chance.